# jQuery/Ajax success method implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following jQuery function on DOM ready:

```
$.ajax({
  url : '/weather/',
  type: 'GET',
  //dataType : "json",
  success : function(data) {
    alert("success");
    var jsondata = Object.keys(data);
    alert(jsondata);
    location = "testing";

    alert(data.weather);
    weather = data.weather;
    $("location").text(location);
  }
  }).setTimeout(executeQuery, 500);
```

The ajax call returns a proper json which I am using to change the values of my html. However, when this line executes,

```
$("location").text(location);
```

the page gets redirected to a url which appends the value of 'location' from the above line. I have used these lines elsewhere, without using success function call.

Can someone help me with what I should do to prevent this redirect from happening?

Comment: The jQuery selector will find a DOM node. However, in this case it will go to the document.location property which is incorrect. The selector is likely missing an id ("#") or class (".") identifier. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the problem lies in variable name you are using.

Don't use `location` since, if you assign any string to `location`, it redirects to the given string.

Like `location="http://nettpals.com";` will redirect to my site.

Use any other variable name like `loc`

Also, if you are targeting a class, prefix it with `.` and if you are targeting id, prefix it with `#`

Like `$('.location')` or `$('#location')`.

When you use `$('location')`, you are trying to match location element `<location></location>`, which obviously is not what you want.

Comment: Ah, fair enough - so it wasn't $("location").text(location) causing the problem but instead location = "testing"

Didn't occur to me that this callback would've been in the window scope.

Comment: I mean in this case location and window.location are the same thing. It's probably possible to play with scope in such a way that you can use the location variable, but not worth it. Maybe even just using var location = "" would have done it.

Comment: Like you said, 'location' is redirecting to the site. I changed it to a different variable and all works fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For one, your class or id selector is invalid. Should be either:

```
$(".location").text(location);
```

or

```
$("#location").text(location);
```

Depending on whether your html markup uses a class or id of "location", respectively.

Also, in this particular case, your lack of the word var:

```
var location = "testing";
```

Is causing the browser to assume the top level window scope. window.location is the property that redirects when you set it's value.

Comment: Yeah, using `$("location")` will redirect the webpage which I'm guessing isn't the objective. +1

Comment: I figured it was something like that but the OP implies that quotation marks weren't used. Prolly just an oversight or something.

Comment: Ah whoops. Forgot the quotation marks in my comment. Yep, using the selector like in the OP was going to just return or set the `document.location` object.

Comment: I tried using this suggestion, it still gets redirected as mentioned above. `$("#location").text(location);`